# Replacing in Pandas?Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace "hel-abc-2021-03-27.xyz" with "hello-2021-03-27" in a Dataframe. str.replace() is not an option because date may vary.

Comment: `str.replace()` replaces parts of strings as well: `pd.Series(["hel-abc-2021-03-27.xyz", "hel-abc-2021-02-15.xyz"]).str.replace("hel-abc", "hello")` results in `hello-2021-03-27.xyz, hello-2021-02-15.xyz`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to prepend the text `hello-` to the date occurring anywhere in the column value, you could use `str.replace` as follows:

```py
df["col"] = df["col"].str.replace('^.*\b(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\b.*$', r'hello-\1')
```